# what is the fastest way to check IEnumerable Count is greater than zero without loop through all records

Tags: c#, ienumerable

i know everyone says to avoid doing something like this because its very slow (just to find out if there is 0)

```
  IEnumerable<MyObject> list;
  if (list.Count() > 0)
  { 
  }
```

but what is the best alternative when all i need to do is find out if the list has a count of 0 or if there are items in it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `list.Any()`. It returns true if it finds an element. Implementation wise, it would be:

```
using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
{
  return enumerator.MoveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
public static IsEmpty(this IEnumerable list)
{
    IEnumerator en = list.GetEnumerator();
    return !en.MoveNext();
}
```

Just start enumerating, and if you can move onto the first item, it's not empty. Also, you can check if the IEnumerable also implements ICollection, and if so, call its .Count property.

Answer (score 0):

Also check for null and count as `if (!list.IsNullOrEmpty()) { ... }`

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns true if collection is null or empty.
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source == null || !source.Any();
}
```